# С++ Как добавить программу в автозагрузку без прав администратора

Tags: c++, реестр, автозапуск, службы

Написал я маленькую программу, которая в свою очередь запускает другую программу. И мне нужно добавить первую программу в автозагрузу желательно через реестр или службы и обязательно бз прав администратора, но я не знаю как это сделать, только учусь.

Comment: Набор ваших вопросов наводит меня на мысли о троянописательстве, не надо так.

Comment: Я так и думал, что вы про это подумаете, но это не так. Как добавить программу в автозагрузку я знаю, но это с правами админа, а вот как сделать без них это уже другое дело(Это мое личное мнение). А вот моеи позапрошлом вопросе я просто хотел узнать есть ли такая возможность запустить 1 программу в теле другой.

Comment: ну и положите ее пользователю в папку "Автозагрузка" `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` она для этого и предназначена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде через `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` можно без админских прав. Но это для текущего юзера.

Второй вариант - получить через `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()` каталог автозапуска главного меню (параметр `CSIDL_STARTUP`) и прописать туда программу.